# Old STI 105 shift lever fell off

Tags: shimano, brake-levers

[image: The fallen item]

Hello,

While riding home last night, my brake lever fell off. It's an older item on an older bike. What's the process to re-attached one of these?

Comment: worst case, the other lever will be identical, so if you carefully took the other brake apart you should be able to learn how it hangs together

Comment: Do you have all the other pieces?  The bolt that held it on, and the springs, etc.?

Comment: @JohnZwinck pretty sure that stuff all went flying too. The shift lever remains, and works as a brake lever in its own right, but I don't trust it whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you've lost some of the other bits.  This kills the brifter.

Seriously, just buy a replacement, probably you can find it used for $50.  Normally you'd redo the bar tape in order to replace the entire shifter, but if you want to avoid that, you could probably swap the entire internals of the new unit into the old body (I say probably because it may be a bit fiddly and perhaps not worth the trouble, and everyone needs new bar tape anyway!).

Comment: Indeed, sourcing parts for an old brifter (or even a new one) is nearly impossible. You can find new 7+ speed brifters in the Shimano Tourney, Claris, Sora, Tiagra, etc. lines or from Microshift. If you want something which is vintage, you'll have to scour ebay or something.